# Google Speech API v1beta1 very slow?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-speech-api

I was super excited when learning that Google has finally released its official speech API for developers. I have always been amazed by how great Google's speech recognition works in Android, Chrome, and other products.

I created a Google Cloud account, enabled the speech API, and created a few testing scripts following the [Google Speech API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/). The accuracy is super high, but the speed is insanely slow. An 18-second audio file would take their engine around 16 seconds to transcribe! Microsoft Bing Speech API only needs 3-4 seconds to do it!

Has anyone experienced the same? Or is it a problem of my configurations? Any help is highly appreciated!

Here is the code I used:

BASH:

```
time curl "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize?key={MY_API_KEY}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"config":{"encoding":"FLAC","sample_rate":16000,"language_code":"en-US"},"audio":{"uri":"gs://accobot-speech/new_record.flac"}}'
```

Comment: I have also noticed this.

Comment: I get a response in 21 secs with your file. There is a discussion here too https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/detail?id=94

Answer (score 0):

To date, the best reference for this issue remains still [the reply published in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/detail?id=94) for the Google Platform.