# Google speech recognition api is too slow

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

Actually I am trying to store audio stream from my web page to my nodejs server using socket.io. And after storing it on my server I am trying to perform speech recognition on the stored file. I have following code running well but it is too slow. I have all environment variables and configurations in place. After collecting statistics for many requests the response time is varying between 7 seconds to 18 seconds.

```
var http = require('http');
var wav = require('wav');
var app = http.createServer(function ejecute(request, response) {});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var fileWriter = null;
    socket.on('stream', function(data) {
        if (!fileWriter) {
            fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter('demo.wav', {
                channels: 1,
                sampleRate: 16000,
                bitDepth: 16
            });
        }
        if (!fileWriter._writableState.ended)
            fileWriter.write(data);
    });
    socket.on('end', function(data) {
        fileWriter.end();
        streamingRecognize('demo.wav');
    });
});

function streamingRecognize(filename) {
    const speech = Speech();

    const request = {
        encoding: 'LINEAR16',
        languageCode: 'en-US',
        sampleRateHertz: 16000
    };

    speech.recognize(filename, request)
        .then((results) => {
            const transcription = results[0];

            console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
}

app.listen(3000);
```

Can anyone help me out here? What wrong am I doing?

Here is reference I am using
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/how-to

I can use Web Speech recognizer too. But I need to provide cross browser support.

Comment: Have you found any info for this issue? Using the same audio configurations of your example, I'm getting 1.5 seconds on average. For me, this is still too much, but more acceptable.

Comment: No I am still exploring. I am currently using bing APIs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Speech API v1beta1 very slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029686/google-speech-api-v1beta1-very-slow)